# AWS SNS is not invoking Lambda through another Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have two lambda function, functionA & functionB. I want to trigger functionB using SNS when functionA completes.

```
FunctionA > SNS > FunctionB
```

FunctionA code is ( Just showing the hello world to understand the situation)

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

FunctionB code is

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import urllib3
import json
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    print({
        "message": event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'], 

    })
```

I have configured a SNS topic and subscription and set that as a destination for both on_failure and on_success for functionA

[image]

The same SNS has been used as a trigger for FunctionB
[image]

But when I am testing/running the functionA from AWS console it is not triggering functionB, no logs on cloudwatch - nothing. But when I am manually publishing the message to SNS then functionB is being triggered. I tried to provide the full Lambda and SNS permission to both functions but still it is not working through functionA. Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As per your screenshot, SNS is only triggered on success or on failure of Lambda asynchronous invocation. Hence, make sure you invoke Function A asynchronously. I think triggering from console is by default synchronous.

One way is to use the Invoke API, passing InvocationType as Event.

Or, use S3 or SNS as the function event source. S3 and SNS will trigger Lambda asynchronously. So SNS1 -> Function A -> SNS2 -> Function B.

Comment: Yeah, this should be the issue here. OP said they were testing it via the "test" button on the cloud console, and I'm pretty sure that's a synchronous call

Comment: so how can we run/test the function asynchronously via aws console? @GersonLCSJunior

Comment: If you have to use console, consider the second option in my answer. Create an S3 bucket as trigger to Function A. Then upload a file. These can be done in console and S3 should trigger Function A asynchronously.

Comment: @FaisalShani You can also try testing it using the invoke API, as this answer suggested, via the CLI. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html#examples

Comment: still same issue. I tried to add apigateway to trigger lambda asynch. but still it is not invoking the functionB throgh SNS. when I am manually publishing the message only then functionB is triggered. @RegisterSole

Comment: @FaisalShani The API Gateway > Lambda integration seems to be synchronous by default. I found the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61081164/how-to-invoke-lambda-async-with-aws-apigateway-httpapi) question here on stack overflow to be useful. I can't look into this problem right now, but hopefully that link can help you.